# Inclusion maps on $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

How to show for $1 \leq p  < q < r$ 
the inclusion maps 
$$L^p \cap L^r \rightarrow L^q$$
$$L^q \rightarrow  L^p + L^r$$
are continuous.

where the norms are defined in the following:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334628/lp-space-interpolation-norm

Thanks a lot for your help!